# How to connect Microsoft SQL Server (IaaS) using API from IBM Datastage 11.7.1.2

Tags: datastage

We are trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server installed in an Azure VM (IaaS) from Datastage using API.

Currently, we are using JDBC connector to connect to Microsoft SQL Server (IaaS) using a service account and its password. But, on a new server, we have to reset the password every three months in Azure. Also, same service account is being used by other applications.

We have to create the change request to reflect the new password in the datastage PROD environment. Also, we are getting separated service account to use in Datastage.

To avoid the password reset or lock issue, we are planning use API to get the password for connecting to the DB.

API DB connection is working in Alteryx. Can you please let us know is it possible to connect and ways to do so in Datastage 11.7.1.2. Also, please let me know any other feasible solution for this problem, if the API connection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to fetch the password via command line interface from your cloud service.

Store the password as datastage environment variable which is then used in the job.

Use a shell script to update the password. In the script, check first if the password has changed. If it did, run the `dsadmin -envset` command to set the environment variable to a new value. You might need to encrypt the new value using the `encrypt` command located in `.../ASBNode/bin`. Call the script every time before running the parallel job.

*You should test if the change of an environment variable will be recognized by the job just in time when the script and the job are called by the same sequence. It might not work if the param is passed-through by the sequence.*

Please read the IBM docs about the commands I mentioned.